# How would I make this Collider work better in Java?(it currently sticks to walls)

Tags: java, collision-detection

```
if(getBounds().intersects(go.getBounds())) {
    x += -velX;
    y += -velY;         
}
```

The getBounds() method returns a rectangle. The intersects() method checks if they intersect and sends true or false; these work perfectly. The problem with making both the x and y value add -velX and -velY is that it makes the object stick to the "go" object. I would like to be able to push up against the "go" object and still slide across it on the axis parallel to the face that is touching the object(pardon my shitty explaining).

Comment: It might be helpful to illustrate what you're asking, as well as what's currently happening.

Comment: In case of intersection you need to switch sign of `velX` or `velY` depending on which wall you hit.

Comment: You basically have 2 points: where the object was, where it is now (inside `go`). Then you have the geometry and coordinates of `go`. Then you must calculate the 3rd point, where you want the object to end up. Draw these on paper. Then you need to do some basic 2D geometry calculations... Try working on this, adding more information (such as these drawings you need to do to sort it out in your head) and code (such as entire movement code) to the question.